# Example for OCR with ANN in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I'm new in OpenCV and I want to implement OCR with ANN. I try to search for example but not see any example that use ANN with Image Processing.

Then I see this example [basicOCRwithANN](https://trac.vime-it.de/blackbird/browser/trunk/src/tests/ocr/basicOCR.cpp) but when I classify it has error rate more than 90% when I try this code

Can someone show me an example that use ANN to implement OCR or Image Processing

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is download the full zip available at the [main page of the project](https://trac.vime-it.de/blackbird/browser/trunk?order=name#images), by clicking on the link that says `Zip Archive`.

This application uses Qt, so you better install it on your system.

You need to do one quick change in the code before compiling it. Go to the **src** directory and open **main.cpp** and add the following instruction before `#if QUICKSTART`:

```
#undef QUICKSTART
```

To compile this application on Linux, execute the following command inside the **src** directory:

```
g++ main.cpp blackbird.cpp tests/lkdemo.cpp tests/ocr/mainOCR.cpp tests/rectifytest.cpp tests/camshift.cpp tests/ocr/basicOCR.cpp tests/StreamImportExport.cpp tests/ocr/basicFunctions.cpp pipeline/Pipeline.cpp pipeline/Properties.cpp pipeline/MarkerArea.cpp pipeline/Utils.cpp pipeline/modules/perspective_correction/Blob.cpp pipeline/modules/perspective_correction/BlobExtraction.cpp pipeline/modules/perspective_correction/BlobResult.cpp pipeline/modules/output/Output.cpp pipeline/modules/test_module/TestModule.cpp pipeline/modules/beamer/Beamer.cpp pipeline/modules/beamer_calibration/BeamerCalibration.cpp pipeline/modules/perspective_correction/PerspectiveCorrect.cpp view/View.cpp -o main -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -I/opt/qt_47x/include/ -L/opt/qt_47x/lib/ -lQtGui -lQtCore
```

This will generate an executable named **main**. **Note** that `-I/opt/qt_47x/include/` refers to the locations where Qt headers are in my system and `-L/opt/qt_47x/lib/` specifices Qt libraries directory. These 2 paths are most probably different on your system, so you need to adjust them appropriately.

Then to execute **main** you need to go to the previous directory and run `./src/main` and choose option number 3. Wait around 5-10 minutes until the network is trained and a new window will pop up. This window let's you draw (hopefully a number), and when you are finished press **C** on your keyboard to classify the image and watch the result on the console.

If this is not the way to do it, I believe you are capable of discovering how to use the application yourself since the compilation of the app is already done.

**EDIT:**

In that case, [download](http://blog.damiles.com/resources/basicOCR.zip) and test the [latest available package](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/). This package brings CMake project files that makes the compilation easier. It also improves a lot the precision rate of the classification. But I don't know if this version is using ANN. Maybe you'll have to do some Frankenstein programming with the 2 versions.

Comment: I can compile this code but when I classify it has error rate more than 90%. That mean it can't classify, not can't compile.

Comment: I see. Updated answer brings link to the latest package available. Detection of hand writing numbers is much much better.

Comment: Thank you but I used KNN before and it take a long time when classify that why I want to use ANN instead KNN.

Comment: Ok, but the new project seems to be a lot faster on my machine than the other one from the trunk you referenced. I don't know why, maybe it uses less images to train but it may be worth to check it out anyway.

Comment: If you separate train and classify. You'll see how fast that ANN classify. It's real that ANN is take long time when train but it's very accurately (if use correct parameter) and very fast.